# Primary election with Priority in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have my mongo cluster in 3 DCs.

DC1 - 3 nodes
DC2 - 3 nodes
DC3 - 3 nodes

DC1 is of high priority following by DC2 and then DC3. So, DC1 will be given 1st priority for PRIMARY election followed by DC2 and then DC3.

Assume, one of the Node in DC1 is primary and data is in sync with DC3, but not in DC2. Now, DC1 goes down. Due to priority one of the node in DC2 is supposed to become PRIMARY, but it is stale. So, which node will become PRIMARY? Is it going to be one of the Node from DC2 or one of the node from DC3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB applies database operations on the primary and then records the operations on the primary’s oplog. The secondary members then copy and apply these operations in an asynchronous process.

The priority settings of replica set members affect both the timing and the outcome of elections for primary. Higher-priority members are more **likely** to call elections, and are more **likely** to win. They are likely to win but not surely.

The oplog determines which node should become primary. First the secondary (for short time) with lower priority can become primary if it has more oplog (i.e. it is updated).After a replica set has a stable primary, the election algorithm will make a “best-effort” attempt to have the secondary with the highest priority available call an election. A lower priority instance can be elected as primary for brief periods, even if a higher priority secondary is available. Replica set members continue to call elections until the highest priority member available becomes primary.